# Change one letter in a string in Perl 6

Tags: raku

It should be very simple, but I can't find an instrument to do it without making a `list` with `.comb`.
I have a `$string` and an  (`0 < $index < $string.chars - 1`). I need to make a `$new_string`, whose element with number `$index` will be changed, say, to 'A'.

```perl6
my $string = 'abcde';
my $index = 0; # $new_string should be 'Abcde'
my $index = 3; # $new_string should be 'abcAe'
```

Comment: Strings are immutable in Perl6. Per the documentation: "Objects of type Str are immutable." [`class Str`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str)

Comment: Maybe you can consider using [`subst-mutate`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#method_subst-mutate) to change the string.

Comment: @callyalater I know. That's why I want to make a `$new_string`.

Comment: @callyalater The problem is not how to change the source string (I don't need that). I want to change only one letter with known `$index` and put the result into another variable.

Comment: How about `'abcde'.subst(/./, 'A') :nth($index)`? Note: Indexing with the `:nth` adverb starts at 1.

Comment: As I remember `:nth` means the number of the match, not its index. If `$index == 0`, it returns an error.

Comment: That's a solution. We have just put `:nth($index +1)` !

Comment: I felt the solution was somewhere near. :) Please, make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I would recommend using:

```perl6
my $string = 'abcde';
my $index = 0;

( my $new-string = $string ).substr-rw( $index, 1 ) = 'A';

say $string;     # abcde
say $new-string; # Abcde
```

If you wanted to stay away from a mutating operation:

```perl6
sub string-index-replace (
  Str $in-str,
  UInt $index,
  Str $new where .chars == 1
){

  ( # the part of the string before the value to insert
    $in-str.substr( 0, $index ) xx? $index
  )
  ~
  ( # add spaces if the insert is beyond the end of the string
    ' ' x $index - $in-str.chars
  )
  ~
  $new
  ~
  ( # the part of the string after the insert
    $in-str.substr( $index + 1 ) xx? ( $index < $in-str.chars)
  )
}

say string-index-replace( 'abcde', $_, 'A' ) for ^10
```

```
Abcde
aAcde
abAde
abcAe
abcdA
abcdeA
abcde A
abcde  A
abcde   A
abcde    A
```

Comment: Thanks! The 1st variant is probably the simplest, I missed this feature of `substr-rw`. And the 2nd one is simply beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

To change just a single letter in the string, you can use the [`subst`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#method_subst-mutate) method on type [`Str`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str):

```
my $string = 'abcde';
my $index = 0;
my $new_string = $string.subst: /./, 'A', :nth($index+1); # 'Abcde'
$index = 3;
$new_string = $string.subst: /./, 'A', :nth($index+1);    # 'abcAe'
```

The "indexing" for `:nth` starts at 1. What `:nth` really means is "replace nth match alone". Because our regex only matches a single character, `:nth` acts like an index (even though it technically is not).